# Extend volume group with adjacent unallocated space

Tags: lvm

I want to grow my volume group to use the unallocated space next to it.

```
 Name              Flags            Part Type    FS Type                  [Label]               Size (MB)

                                                     Unusable                                            1.05       *
  sda1              Boot              Primary        ext3                                            27563.92   *
                                      Logical        Free Space                                          1.02   *
  sda5                                Logical        ext4                                              524.33   *
  sda6              NC                Logical        LVM2_member                                    125002.85   *
                                      Logical        Free Space                                     824910.55   *
  sda2                                Primary        swap                                             6652.17   *
                                                     Unusable                                            0.64   *
  sda3                                Primary        ntfs                     [BackUp]             1015740.26   *
                                                     Unusable                                            2.19   *
```

So the free space after sda6 should be added to sda6 (which is my volume group). 
How can I achieve this?

sda5, sda6 and the unallocated space (824GB) are part of the extended partition sda4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. fdisk to create a new partition #7 containing the space after sda6
2. reboot to ensure that all partitions are registered properly and the device names are created.
3. pvcreate /dev/sda7
4. vgextend [volumegroupname] /dev/sda7
5. vgdisplay -v [volumegroupname]     ;; to see the added size and # extents

Now more space is contained in volumegroup.

I presume that you are extending one of the logical volumes within the VG that already contains an ext2/ext3 filesystem.  For safety I'd suggest unmounting the logical volume that you want to expand.

5. lvextend -l +[numberextentsfreefrom#5] [logicalvolumepath]
6. resize2fs [logicalvolumepath]

Your logicalvolumepath will now have more available space.

Comment: Hi, after step 4 I can remove sda7 isn't it?

Comment: Can I do that by issuing vgreduce --all [volumegroupname]?

Comment: Once /dev/sda7 is contained in the VG, you CANNOT remove it from the partitioning information.

Comment: If the question is how to reduce the space, then you'll have to do things in the reverse order: resize2fs DOWN, lvreduce, and then finally vgreduce.

Comment: I was wondering what the aim is of the extra created partition. It works so I am happy, its probably not in my way, but its an extra partition without any meaning.

Comment: TIP: To extend your logical volume to the full size of free space in the volume group change Part 2 Step 1 from "lvextend -l +[numberextentsfreefrom#5] [logicalvolumepath]" to "lvextend -l +100%free [logicalvolumepath]"